# Remote Shutdown & Waking Up Computers

Tags: c#, dhcp, wake-on-lan

Been searching for a proper way to remotely shut down every single computer within my organization (approx. 1600 machines) at the weekends, unless stated otherwise by the logged-on user.

I've built a client which runs on every station. The client is in charge of starting processes remotely and its current purpose is to display a message which notifies the user about the upcoming shutdown. If the user chooses to cancel the operation, his computer will not be powered off by my script.

It works great for all the logged-on users, but now I need to deal with the locked machines and the ones who are currently in 'sleep' mode.

I use psshutdown to remotely shutdown every single computer that has not clicked the cancellation button when the pop-up showed.

the psshutdown deals with the locked machines, but the ones sleeping can not be accessed due to the lack of communication.

Therefore, I've also added a script that wakes the computer by its Mac Address, and then preforms the shutdown operation all over again.

I believe there is a better and more appropriate method to achieve my goals, but in case there isn't, I would like to know how I can get a list of all of organization computers Mac Addresses (even the ones that are off). I was thinking about "arp -a", but it only displays a small list of computers - the one connected to one certain switch, instead of the entire organization.

Or better yet, is there any better way to solve my current issue? Maybe by using some other method to remotely shutdown a bunch of PCs despite some of them being unreacheable (sleeping).

Comment: Why do you need to turn off the computers that are sleeping? Are you sure it needs to be done? It seems like you've solved 99% of your problem, and now are brooding over something that maybe doesn't even matter. If this is for power savings, for example, it might not be worth it. Also, have you considered using scheduled tasks for this instead? You could just register a scheduled tasks to do the shutdown, and the computer can wake itself at the scheduled time if its asleep.

Comment: I'd rather not have 1600 tasks spread all over the organization, but have something a bit more organized. Also I need full control of the script and to posses the ability to disable it whenever I feel like it.

Comment: You already have a remote client for the machines. Have it register the machine's MAC address on startup with the central location where you're running your scripts. There are technologies, like [Intel's AMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology), that allow remote boot/shutdown (as well as anything else you'd possibly like to manage); this requires hardware support, however. Disclaimer: I have no experience with it.

Comment: No need to manually create 1600 tasks. You can use GPO to control all of them over the domain. And if you don't have a domain, just use your application to automatically enable or disable those tasks as needed.